# bash query through Python subprocess, bash variables wont expand

Tags: python, bash, ssh, subprocess

I'm doing a bash query using `subprocess` over SSH (don't ask). The query includes using `find` with the `-exec` option, however, on the remote target host, `{}` won't expand properly, when viewing what the query actually does on the target host.

For example: `find / -name "hello.txt" -exec echo {} \;` where `{}` should read `hello.txt` but it merely reads just as `{}`.

So, what I'm I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted some code, but my guess is that you are not including `shell=True` in your subprocess arguments, which is necessary for the variable expansion.  For example:

```
subprocess.Popen('find / -name "hello.txt" -exec echo {} \;', shell=True)
```

Comment: Yupp, I know :-) Code is on another machine. But you're correct, using `shell=False`.